# UIBarButtonItem registers click event next to button, not on button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

I got the popup, used at 2 locations within my app, one time in a navigation controller one time without navigation controller, 
i got one button in a uitoolbar (select button) but this button has it's own life for some reason

The one in the navigation controller is working perfectly.

But the one called without navigation controller resizes this popup so i resized it back in the code like

```
    - (void)showModal:(UIViewController *)controller
    {
        [controller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil]; //Method used without navigationcontroller
        [controller.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0, 600, 748)]; //resize => button doesn't work at all
        //[controller.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 748)]; //resize => button only registers click event left from the actual button
        //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"show modal" object:controller]; // Method used within navigationcontroller
    }
```

I've been looking all over google but i can't find anything on this problem.
Hope I have more luck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easy way to sort this problem out is to put it in a UINavigationController and use that to pop up. Then you don't have to use a UIToolBar.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerToPopUp];
    [viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

This way the viewController you are presenting stays simple and you already know the button works when it is a navigation controller :)